# Multiple rows match, but I only want one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sometimes I wish to perform a join whereby I take the largest value of one column. Doing this I have to perform a max() and a groupby- which prevents me from retrieving the other columns from the row which was the max (beause they were not contained in a GROUP BY or aggregate function).

To fix this, I join the max value back on the original data source, to get the other columns. However, my problem is that this sometimes returns more than one row.

So, so far I have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Col1, Max(Col2) FROM Table GROUP BY Col1) tab1
JOIN
    (SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table) tab2
ON tab1.Col2 = tab2.Col2
```

If the above query now returns three rows (which match the largest value for column2) I have a bit of a headache.

If there was an extra column- col3 and for the rows returned by the above query, I only wanted to return the one which was, say the minimum Col3 value- how would I do this?

Comment: What sql-server version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+. Then you can do it like this:

**CTE way**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC) AS RowNbr,
        table.*
    FROM
        table
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

**Subquery way**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC) AS RowNbr,
        table.*
    FROM
        table
    ) AS T
WHERE
    T.RowNbr=1
```

Comment: Right. Sorry about that. Update the answer

Answer (score 1):

As I got it can be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Col1, Max(Col2) FROM Table GROUP BY Col1) tab1
JOIN
    (SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table) tab2
ON tab1.Col2 = tab2.Col2 and Col3 = (select min(Col3) from table )
```

Comment: Will this still select the min col3 per col1? Also, if two values exist as the minimum col3, wont this still return two results?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL-Server 2005 or later You can make use of [Window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) here. I have chosen [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) but it is not hte only option.

```
;WITH T AS
(   SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC) [RowNumber]
    FROM    Table
)
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

The `PARTITION BY` within the `OVER` clause is equivalent to your group by in your subquery, then your `ORDER BY` determines the order in which to start numbering the rows. In this case `Col2 DESC` to start with the highest value of col2 (Equivalent to your `MAX` statement).